# Запуск java приложения из angular сервиса

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Есть приложение `Angular v12` обернутое в `Electron`, на старте оно должно запустить модуль на `java` и дождаться вывода `Application started` для инициализации `app.component` (дело происходит в `BootstrapService`). При этом запущенное `java` приложение, это ясное дело не скрипт, и до конца не выполнится, и результат выполнения не вернет. Я пытаюсь использовать `window.require('child_process')` для этого:

```
private execute(command: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise<string>(
    (resolve) => {
      this.childProcess
        .exec(command, (error, stdout, _) =>
          error ? resolve(error.message) : resolve(stdout));
  });
}
```

Обычные "конечные" скрипты `execute` нормально выполняет.

Проблема тут:

```
public run(): Promise<boolean> {
  return this.execute('java --version')
    .then((stdout) => {
      if (stdout.includes('java')) {
        this.execute('java -jar app.jar').then();
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => resolve(true));
      } else {
        window.alert('Critical ERROR Java v11 required');
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => resolve(false));
      }
    });
}
```

С командой `java -jar app.jar` метод `execute(command: string): Promise<string>` работает бесконечно, так как выполнение `java -jar app.jar` не когда не заканчивается. Как мне дождаться вывод по момента появления ключевых `Application started` слов и **только тогда** вызвать `resolve(true)` или `resolve(false)` по таймауту или найдя `Application fail` в логе?

Comment: 1) такие вещи нельзя делать в рендер-процессе, их нужно делать в мейне и передавать сигнал по ipc 2) чтобы что-то прочитать нужно подписаться на stdin/out/error 3) метки вопроса вообще не в тему

Comment: @nörbörnën, вроде в render тоже должно работать?

Comment: @Qwertiy будет работать. но рендер на столько не предназначен для подобных манипуляций, что электрон выбросил `remote` в отдельную (внешнюю) либу и большими красными буквами написал в доке что-то типа «не прислоняться»